# Images(base64) not uploading correctly

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, base64

Unfortunately I'm facing some issues when I try to upload some images from an android device to a database.
The images are in a folder. This folder contains images as well as other stuff. I don't know the names of the images and I need to upload only the images(jpg). Before I upload the images I need to encode them with base64.

First I get the jpg files from the folder. Then I get the ID out of the image name. After that I encode it via base64:

```
Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        File dir = new File(path);
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                pics = new File(String.valueOf(files[i]));
                id = String.valueOf(files[i]);
                String sub = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                int index = sub.indexOf("_");
                String book;
                if (index >= 0) {
                    book = sub.substring(0, index);
                    ID = book;
                    Log.e("ID", ID);
                }
                Bitmap imagex = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pics.getAbsolutePath());
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                imagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
                byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
                Image = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                try {
                    new HttpAsyncTask(ID,Image,Nummer).execute("https://....");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("InputStream", e.getMessage());
                }

                Log.e("PICS", id);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
public String POST(String url) {
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = classxy.getNewHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        String json = "";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        jsonObject.put("bookId", ID);
        jsonObject.put("imageString", Image);
        jsonObject.put("imageNumber", Nummer);

        json = jsonObject.toString();

        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        httpPost.setHeader("Apikey", data);
        httpPost.setHeader("Modul", "upload_image");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();


        if (inputStream != null)
            result = classxy.convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Fehler!";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    int num = Integer.parseInt(Nummer);
    num++;
    Nummer = Integer.toString(num);
    return result;
}
```

---

```
public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final Object ID, Image, Nummer;

    public HttpAsyncTask(Object ID, Object Image, Object Nummer) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Nummer = Nummer;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return POST(urls[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result.matches("(.*)false(.*)")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Log.e("RESPONSE", result);
    }
}
```

It does encode the images via base64 and it does upload some of the images. Unfortunately it uploads only the first image or one image multiple times. It never uploads the correct amount of images in the correct order. I've been sitting on this problem for a while now and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would strongly advise if you use something like okhttp to perform http request.
https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes

Comment: I agree with Vannen. In addition to being not very good overall, HttpClient is deprecated in newer Android versions.

Comment: How it supposed to work:  1. I read the first image from the folder. 2. get the ID from the filename 3. Encode the image with base64 4.Send the first(encoded) image to the server. 5. receive server result. Then continue with the next image and so on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program doesn't seem to be thread-safe at all.

Your fields `ID`, `Image` and `Nummer` are updated with every iteration of the for loop. Most likely the loop has already finished before `POST` runs for the first time. Your observation would support this assumption:

> Unfortunately it uploads only the first image or one image multiple times.

You can observe this by logging every access to these fields. You'll find, that it's not alternating like you expect it to be.

Therefore you should implement everything without using these fields at all. Instead use local variables and pass these around. Using the `Nummer` field could be usefull if you want to use it for more than one upload. But it might be better to use an `int` directly:

```
upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String ID = "", Image;
        int Nummer = 0;
        [...]

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            if (files[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                [...]

                try {
                    new HttpAsyncTask(ID,Image,Integer.toString(Nummer++)).execute("https://....");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("InputStream", e.getMessage());
                }

                Log.e("PICS", id);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
public String POST(String url, String ID, String Image, String Nummer) {
    InputStream inputStream;
    try {
        [...]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    //int num = Integer.parseInt(Nummer);
    //num++;
    //Nummer = Integer.toString(num);
    return result;
}
```

---

```
public class HttpAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final String ID, Image, Nummer;

    public HttpAsyncTask(String ID, String Image, String Nummer) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Image = Image;
        this.Nummer = Nummer;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return POST(urls[0], ID, Image, Nummer);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok it almost works now, which is great :D When I upload four pics it uploads images 2-4. It only skips pic one now. But i gues I'll get that figured out somehow. I can't thank you enough man! Thanks for your help you did a great job!

Comment: Figured it out. For some strange reason the API doesn't accept "1" as Number and ignored the request with imagenumber 1 so I just set the starting count to 2. Now it works perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: I would have expected, it wouldn't like a number of 0. But good to hear it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

In My suggestion Dont call Asynctask directly from for loop because there are no any monitor on we can set for which image selected.

So Go through below steps:

1) In for loop get all images ID,Name and number and store it to ArrayList

2) Check ArrayList first is empty or not
if not then get first position ID, Image and number

call new HttpAsyncTask(ID,Image,Integer.toString(Nummer++)).execute("https://....");

3) In HttpAsyncTask `onPostExecute(String result)` method
first remove first position data
then create

```
for loop (i=0;i<ArrayList.Size();i++) {
    ID=ArrayList first position data ID
    Image=ArrayList first position data IMAGE
    number=ArrayList first position data number

Call new HttpAsyncTask(ID,Image,Integer.toString(Nummer++)).execute("https://....");
```

}

So here first Image send by then after second then after third up to your list not empty and every time different image selected.

Thats it...